# Java date is changing when updating date field in Oracle DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, java.util.date

I am parsing date field from xml and store it into oracle db for my requirement. my xml date looks like

```
<BirthDate>1960-10-24T00:00:00</BirthDate>
```

during unmarhsalling the xml, i am getting XMLGregorianCalendar data type for this date field.So, am converting this object into java.util.Date and then save it to oracle DB. But it is updated with one day minus. For example, it is updated like **23-10-1960.**. How to fix this issue and get it updated with the actual date on the xml.

This is my code:

```
myEntity.setBirthDate(xmlDomain.getBirthDate().toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
```

Comment: This is likely a timezone issue but without seeing any of your code it is impossible for anyone to do anything but guess.

Comment: Well, I faced exactly the same issue sometime back. As @JimGarrison pointed out there is timezone difference what your oracle db considers and what your java runtime considers.

Comment: @JimGarrison : i have updated with my code..

Comment: As already pointedout, are your Oracle DB and Java in the same timezone?

Comment: java timezone is IST and DB timezone is UTC

Comment: Are you writing to a date-only type column in your database or date-with-time column? Tell us *exactly* the data type.

Comment: @BasilBourque : We have timestamp in DB

Comment: @Saravanan `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`? Two *very* different things.

Comment: @BasilBourque: Timestamp without time zone

Answer (score 2):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You should not be using [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html). That terrible class was supplanted years ago with the adoption of JSR 310.

## *java.time*

[Convert](http://toGregorianCalendar()) from your legacy [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) to the modern [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class by way of another terrible legacy class, [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#%3Cinit%3E()).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myXmlGregCal.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime() ;
```

### `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column

To write this moment to the database in a column of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, using JDBC 4.2, convert the `ZonedDateTime` to an `OffsetDateTime`. Oddly, the JDBC spec requires support for `OffsetDateTime` but not `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;
```

Pass to your prepared statement.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

### `DATE` column

If writing to a date-only type column, akin to the SQL-standard type `DATE`, then use `LocalDate` class.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;  // If the zone of that ZonedDateTime object is the zone by which you want to perceive the date.
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

[image]